# Odoo 15 changing the website/portal datetime picker format?

Tags: xml, datetime, web, odoo, datetimepicker

In Odoo 15, is there a way to change the datetime Picker format from 12 hours to 24 hours ?

[image: Sample from Portal]

##**UPDATE**##
This is datetime-local field so it will be formatted depending on the browser/operating system's datetime format. Is there any function to bypass it ?

Answer (score 1):

In the user settings. Go to the language settings, you can specify the Time Format. Use %H:%M:%S to specify a 24-hour format.

Comment: Thank you for replying, but the solution you provided is for the backend interface, and not for the portal/wesbite interface.